# GwtQuery - fadeIn one after another

Tags: gwt, gwtquery, gquery

I want to add fade-in animation for couple of widgets one after another.
I reviewed the doc, but it only does first fade-in.

```
$(myWidget1).fadeIn(new Function(){
      public boolean f(Event e){
            //tried to add the second fade-in for myWidget2, but no result 
            return true;
      }
});
```

How do I achieve fade-in one after another in this way or, is there another way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var widgets = $('.widget');
        var fader = function(widget_n){
            if (widget_n < widgets.length) {
                $(widgets.get(widget_n)).fadeIn('slow', function(){
                    fader(widget_n +1);
                });    
            }
        };

        if (widgets.length > 0) {
            fader(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: how do I do this with GWT?

Comment: does GWT provide an animation method with a callback once the animation has completed? Could you also load the jQuery library and use that in addition?

Comment: bitten by the 5 minute edit rule. trying again: Apparently, there is a gwtquery library you might want to look into: [link]http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#The_animate%28%29_method  Notice that the animate() function provides the same kind of callback function that jQuery's fadeIn() has.

Comment: That's working. But still have an issue. Let say I have a parent content and inside that another content but smaller than parent. Within that child content I have a TextBox. When I animate this TextBox, it only animates inside the child content. I want it to be animated over the parent content. Can you help me for that?

Answer (score 1):

Check my example here : http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/branches/droppable_1_0/demo/DraughtsSample/DraughtsSample.html

I use the fadeIn GQuery method method to fade in each piece of the board. You can find the code there : http://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/source/browse/trunk/droppable/sample/src/main/java/gwtquery/plugins/droppable/client/draughtssample/CheckerBoard.java#116

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the .each() function to loop through your "widgets".

```
var map = { 
  'mywidget1': '#mywidget1', 
  'mywidget2': '#mywidget2' 
}; 
$.each(map, function(key, value) {
  $(value).fadeIn(...);
});
```

or if they all have a something in common (i.e. class of tag combination etc.) this would be even easier.

See [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) jQuery API

Comment: That will start simultaneous (more or less) fadeIn() on all the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding an incorrect method: `f(Event)` is used for events, change it by `f()`:

```
$(myWidget1).fadeIn(new Function(){
  public void f() {
     $(myOtherWidget).fadeIn();
  }
});
```